# Azure maps indoor module: How to access to Indoor Map GeoJSON from Azure Maps Web SDK

Tags: azure-maps

I have been working on a project using Azure Indoor Maps. I started to use the Azure Maps Web SDK. I have looked for a way to loop to all features that are loaded automatically by the SDK, without making a request to WFS API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/v2/wfs/get-feature.

As I see the map loaded, I think that this information should be accessible directly by SDK, and I do not need to create another request. But maybe I am wrong.

I have found a method that does something similar to what I need **[getRenderedShapes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-control/atlas.layermanager?view=azure-maps-typescript-latest#getRenderedShapes_Position___Point___BoundingBox__string___Layer___Array_string___Layer___Expression_)** but it only returns the features that are visible when the method is called, and I need all the features in the indoor map or in one floor.

Does anybody know if this is possible? On one side I think should be something similar to getRenderedShapes, but on the other side, I think that the front-end only has the visual information and that azure indoor maps use the **Vector tile source** and are optimized in the back-end and only serve to the front-end the required information.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/web-sdk-best-practices#optimize-data-sources

> The Web SDK has two data sources,
>
> GeoJSON source: Known as the DataSource class, manages raw location
> data in GeoJSON format locally. Good for small to medium data sets
> (upwards of hundreds of thousands of features). Vector tile source:
> Known at the VectorTileSource class, loads data formatted as vector
> tiles for the current map view, based on the maps tiling system. Ideal
> for large to massive data sets (millions or billions of features).
>
> Vector tile source: Known at the VectorTileSource class, loads data
> formatted as vector tiles for the current map view, based on the maps
> tiling system. Ideal for large to massive data sets (millions or
> billions of features).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, the map SDK only loads the indoor maps via vector tiles which are condensed set of the data set clipped to areas of the view port. This only loads a small subset of the data. This makes it possible to create a large scalable indoor map platform that in theory could support every building in the world in real time. As you noted, the getRenderedShapes function can retrieve data from the vector tiles, but only those that are in the current viewport (plus a small buffer). I believe the only way to get the data as GeoJSON if via the WFS GetFeatures service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/v2/wfs/get-features